# class files with the same name in two different jars - web application

Tags: java, web-applications, jar, weblogic

I have a class file (Alpha.class) with different implementations but the same name in two different jar files a.jar and b.jar. The application is deployed in Weblogic server. b.jar is included in the application while a.jar is bundled in a shared library that is referenced by the application. 
The problem is that the class file always gets picked up from b.jar but I want it to be picked up from a.jar. Have tried a few things that I found on stack overflow and elsewhere:

- modifying the Manifest.MF of b.jar to include the Class-Path attribute (did not work)
- deploying the jar on weblogic as shared library (did not work)

The problem seems to be that a.jar always gets appended at the end of the class path. Anyway I can alter the class-path at run-time or in general, have a.jar of the shared library over-ride the application's b.jar?

NOTE: This is not a situation where I want to override jars provided by weblogic. I want my own shared library's jars to take priority over application's jars.

Comment: same solution regardless

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson This is ridiculous. Did you even read it?

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson I'm not talking about conflicts between weblogic jars and application jars. I want to override the application jars with the  custom jars present in my own shared library.  It's not even a conflict.